# How to retain attributes of inherited Spark DataFrame Class following a Spark operation on that class

Tags: python, dataframe, class, inheritance, pyspark

I create a new class called **NewDataFrame** with attribute **a_string**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

class NewDataFrame(DataFrame):

    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__(df._jdf,df.sql_ctx)
        self.a_string = "Hello, World."
```

I use the class on some data and am able to print out **a_string**:

```
data = {
     'a': ['yellow', 'red']
    ,'b': [1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

temp = NewDataFrame(sdf)
temp.a_string

Out[]: Hello, World.
```

Now, I filter **temp** to a subset and try to output **a_string** and receive an error because the **filter** method returns a **DataFrame**, not **NewDataFrame**.

```
temp = temp.filter("a='yellow'")
temp.a_string

Out[]: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'a_string'
```

To keep the attribute in the result of a filter, I have tried creating a new method on the **NewDataFrame** class which performs the filter and then feeds the result back into a **NewDataFrame** class, which works, but I do not want to rewrite all the Spark functions in this manner.

Is there a way for the class to have access to the full range of **DataFrame** methods while still retaining the attributes I define in **NewDataFrame**?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same inheritance in Python with no success. The PySpark dataframe has been implemented in a such way to return the Dataframe object after performing the operations. You can look at the source code and see how it has been done:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py

As mentioned in the question, without overriding each function in your subclass it will be difficult to build proper functional class. One another way is you can use initialize Parent object within the child class instead of inheriting from the Parent class.